# Jasperreports creates one empty page from JDBC

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I have a Template like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.3.final using JasperReports Library version 6.4.3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Invoice" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4eedbb89-b4f6-4469-9ab6-f642a1688cf7">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="localdb"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#EEEFF0"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
       .....
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT * from test]]>
    </queryString>
```

And this code for generating:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource datasource;

@RequestMapping(value = "invoice", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity createInvoice() throws JRException, SQLException, IOException {
    InputStream resourceAsStream = PDFReporter.class.getResourceAsStream(BILL_JRXML);
    assert resourceAsStream != null : "No " + BILL_JRXML + " found!";
    JasperReport r = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(resourceAsStream);
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap();
    Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(r, parameters, connection);
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(bos));
    exporter.exportReport();
    connection.close();
    return new ResponseEntity(bos.toByteArray(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But the result is a PDF having only one page that is blank.

I download the PDF and check for errors but the PDF having the lead-in `%PDF-1.4` and the lead-out `%%EOF`.

If I do it in Jaspersoft Studio it works good.

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like wrong connection (wrong db) or you are using another template (not the same as check with Studio)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the table `test` is empty. I never expected to have a empty page!